# Parsing multiple PDFs from text input with PDF Parser library

Tags: php, loops, pdf, foreach, pdf-parsing

I'm attempting to use the [PDF Parser](http://www.pdfparser.org/) PHP library to parse the text from multiple PDFs which are submitted through a form textarea (one PDF URL per line).

The code I'm using is:

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ids = $_POST["textarea"];
foreach(explode("\n", $ids) as $line) {
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($line);
    $text = $pdf->getText();            
    echo $text . '<br />';
?>
```

Note: 'vendor/autoload.php' is a [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) file.

This works as expected when I put only 1 URL into the textarea, but if I put more than one it returns nothing. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my foreach loop or if this library does not support parsing multiple PDFs in a loop... Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You should check your error-logs or enable your error reporting to get more details: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`